# respondsToSelector with different argument types in selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

Suppose we have different Object which have the same method name but with differet argument types like: `getMethod:(NSNumber*)aNumber` and `getMethod:(NSString*)aString`.

How to check with respondsToSelector or through other way, if an object responds to the selector with particular argument type, something like this:

```
[myObjectA respondsToSelector:@selector(getMethod:(NSNumber*))]
```

How do you do this?
Thanks.

Comment: you can not declare two methods with the same name and different parameter-types.

Comment: Ok, suppose we have different types of objects, with the same method name, but with different argument types. What you do then?

Comment: you will have to use the [Objective-C Runtime Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418) directly

Comment: You still can't do it.  You need to have *one* method that takes `id` as its argument and then determine what kind of object it is inside that method.

Comment: Anything more simple than  Runctime Functions? :)

Comment: @borrden no, he can write his own respondsToSelector.

Comment: @OlegDanu no, I dont think so.

Comment: Oh, I see what he means!  Two different classes with the same method names.  Even with writing his own `respondsToSelector` though, he won't be able to distinguish between those two.  Internally they will both be encoded to the same C-string (return type void, one parameter of type `id`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of ways to find type names of arguments for selector.
For example this code will work:

```
Method method = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(someMethod:param2:param3:));
char type[256];
int argsNumber = method_getNumberOfArguments(method);
for (int i = 0; i < argsNumber; i++) {
    method_getArgumentType(method, i, type, 256);
    NSLog(@"%s", type);
}
```

First and second log arguments are system and you are not interested in them, so another tree lines are that you need.

also code below will give you same result

```
NSMethodSignature *sig = [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(someMethod:param2:param3:)];
int args = [sig numberOfArguments];
for (int i = 0; i < args; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%s", [sig getArgumentTypeAtIndex:i]);
}
```

`someMethod:param2:param3:` can have implementation like this for example

```
- (BOOL) someMethod:(NSString *)str param2:(UIView *)view param3:(NSInteger)number
{
    return NO;
}
```

BUT! Of cause we have big but here )) In both cases you will have arguments types names with `const char *` string with length a one symbol. Compiler encodes types name as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html). You can differ int from char but not UIView from NSString. For all id types you will have type name '@' that means it's `id`. Sad but true. Unfortunately I've not found any ways to get whole complete type name or decode given. If you will find this way let me know pls.

So this is solution. Hope you will find the way how to use this approach in your project.

Comment: Thank you Rost! Even if your answer does not directly respond to my question, it explains an interesting way of working with Runtime.

Comment: Hope Apple guys will release a method for my needs in feature releases of the SDK.

Comment: It's doubtful that they will because your needs go against their philosophy of verbose naming.  My suggestion is to simply refactor so that they have names that actually indicate what they are doing.  Even if it is as simple as `getMethodFromNumber:` or `getMethodFromString:`

Answer (score 1):

You wont actually be able to distinguish the methods parameter type but maybe you could do something like this instead:

```
if([myObject isKindOfClass:[A class]])
     [myObjectA getMethod:aNumber];
else if([myObject isKindOfClass:[B class]])
     [myObjectA getMethod:aString];
```

You wont need to check if it responds to the selector since you have checked that its the right type. Maybe your problem is more complicated than this but this should work if its not.